# How can Set character set utf8 and table rows collation in PHP mysql with query

Tags: php, mysql, create-table

I want to make table dynamically in PHP mysql and in table I want to set character set utf8 and its rows collation utf8_general_ci. I have no Clue

Anyone help please?

Here is my create table query:

```
CREATE TABLE `Table name` (
              `id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
              `First name` TEXT( 9 ) NOT NULL,
              `Last name` TEXT NOT NULL,
              `email` TEXT NOT NULL,
              UNIQUE KEY id (id)
            );
```

How can I set "utf8" parameters in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this nadeem

```
CREATE TABLE `Table name` (
              `id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
              `First name` TEXT( 9 ) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
              `Last name` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
              `email` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
              UNIQUE KEY id (id)
            )COLLATE='utf8_general_ci';
```

Do not collate on int, float data types

Comment: Thanx alot deemi thanx alot you save my day +1

Comment: Thanx nadeem, i feel happy to help you